# Kivy. VirtualKeyboard on smartphones. (При открытии сдвигается всё содержимое окна вверх)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Может кто подскажет, как можно реализовать в kivy чтобы при открытии клавиатуры:

1. Она не перекрывала контент при фокусе на инпут, а делала его над самой клавиатурой.
2. Она не выталкивала топбар(тулбар) за переделы экрана.
   softinput может выполнять только 1 пункт.
   Нужен принцип действия как у мессенджеров, когда сообщения как бы заезжают за топбар, даже при открытии клавиатуры. То есть топ бар всегда находится на одной позиции.